# Identify a plant with a thick trunk, leaves have dark green line down the center

Tags: identification

I am in need of identifying this plant that is growing in my flower garden, as i have dogs and children and want to make sure it is safe for them to be around. It is tall with a thick trunk and leaves every few inches that are green with a dark green line down the center. It sort of looks exotic. I have a picture, but can't figure out how to add an attachment.

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.